# Why do I get 7 as output?

Tags: python

```
number = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
cleanedNumber = ''

for i in range(0, len(number)):
    if number[i] in '0123456789':
        cleanedNumber = number[i]

newNumber = int(cleanedNumber)

print("The number is {} ".format(newNumber))
```

The thing that I don't understand with the code above is the output. As the output I get is the number 7. WHY 7?

I know that I'd get if **cleanedNumber += number[i]** was the case. But why do I get 7 when I change **+=** to **=**.

Comment: because it's the last digit in your `number` string

Comment: there's no benefit from using `format()` in your `print()`. Plain `"print(The number is %d" % newNumber)` is sufficient

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Doesn't work, quote at wrong place. And `print("The number is", newNumber)`.

Comment: Ah, too much editing - I missed opening `"` is not at the right place. But you should be able to spot and fix that quickly though

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: do not advertise string replacement with % anymore. there is no benefit to the OP and because of the commonalities with f-strings it is more efficient to just learn `.format()`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Isn't string formatting with `%` "depreciated" for the `.format()` method?

Comment: Is it? I do not know that. Can you point docs or changelog saying so?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski While not marked as "depreciated" the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples) refer to using `'%'` as the "old style". I'd have to look further for official depreciation notes (if any).

Comment: "old style" means nothing really except for one's personal opinion. Unless it's officially deprecated (which I doubt it'd happen) it is fine to use.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Here is the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) discussing the limitations of using it over the `.format()` method.

Comment: But "so what"? Choose tools that fits your needs. It's perfectly sufficient to OP's case and `format()` is like using canon to kill the fly with `format()` bringing no real benefits.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski This is just a subject matter discussion. In this case, sure, but if the store offers a new and improved cannon at no extra cost to you, why not get it and learn how to use it?

Comment: Your argument is invalid. And why not to use? Because in this case it's more typing than plain `%` with no outcome difference.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: as mentioned, in the end it's just easier for a beginner to just learn the more modern and future-proof thing. and your argument about the amount of typing is equally invalid, since a simple comma means even less typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `"7"` is the last digit you iterate over, that is in `'0123456789'`. Take a look at [this](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=number%20%3D%20%229,223,372,036,854,775,807%22%0AcleanedNumber%20%3D%20''%0A%0Afor%20i%20in%20range%280,%20len%28number%29%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20number%5Bi%5D%20in%20'0123456789'%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cleanedNumber%20%3D%20number%5Bi%5D%0A%0AnewNumber%20%3D%20int%28cleanedNumber%29%0A%0Aprint%28%22The%20number%20is%20%7B%7D%20%22.format%28newNumber%29%29%20%20%20%20&cumulative=false&curInstr=70&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false/) if you need further guidance:

Answer (score 1):

You get it because you are no longer using **compound assignment** rather **assignment**. Each time you get to `cleanedNumber = number[i]` you are *assigning* it a new value.

It appears you wish to just get the number from the string. Since you are changing the type to `int` at the end, you also do not care about decimal places otherwise you would call `float`. Given these assumptions, why not just do:

```
number = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
cleanedNumber = int(''.join(number.split(',')))
print("The number is {}".format(cleanedNumber))
```

Otherwise, the changes you would need are:

```
number = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
cleanedNumber = ''

for char in number: # just iterate over the string
    if char.isdigit():
        cleanedNumber += char

cleanedNumber = int(cleanedNumber)

print("The number is {}".format(cleanedNumber))
```

Comment: there is a bug in your code. anyway, using `char.isdigit()` would be more succinct and is about as fast as the set lookup.

Comment: you generated a set of ints, not a set of strings. i took the liberty to edit in the string-method approach.

Comment: @hop yea I just realized the `char in nums` was gonna compare `str` to `int` and leave `''`.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are doing it wrong. Everytime through the loop you are resetting the value of `cleanedNumber` when you should be appending to it:

```
number = "9,223,372,036,854,775,807"
cleanedNumber = ''

for i in range(0, len(number)):
    if number[i] in '0123456789':
        cleanedNumber += number[i]

newNumber = int(cleanedNumber)

print("The number is {} ".format(newNumber))
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.